# Do relational databases execute insert statements in parallel or sequentially?

Tags: database, synchronization, dml

If two users were to execute `INSERT INTO` statements on the same target table at the same time, would these be executed in parallel or in sequence?

Will this behavior change based on whether the target table has a primary key or not?

Is this a defined rule for all relational databases or do different vendors implement this in different ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *general* they will (should) be executed in parallel, also if a primary key is defined.

The behaviour depends heavily on the DBMS. MySQL with MyISAM will e.g. block any further access to a table if DML is being executed against the table. The same is true for SQL Server in the default installation and older DB2 version.

In general if the DBMS is using [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird, MySQL/InnoDB, ...) then you can expect inserts to run in parallel

One thing that *can* block concurrent inserts is if two transactions insert the *same* primary key value. In that case the second transaction will need to wait for the first to either commit (then the second one will get a pk violation error) or rollback (the second one will succeed).

Comment: It can be more complicated than that.  Primary keys are only one instance that might enforce serialization.  Identity/auto increment columns, unique constraints (of which the primary key is an example), and triggers are other situations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Triggers don't serialize inserts - unless this is manually done in the trigger code. Interesting point about identity columns. Is that a shortcoming of the identity/auto_increment concept or is that a result of the underlying index (so it's basically the unique index "problem" again). I primarily use Oracle and PostgreSQL and sequences do not have any concurrency issues there.